# can I assign color to one side of face only?

Tags: materials, color

I'm modeling a bowl of ramen and I would like the bowl to have a stripe going around it.  I can assign the material color to that stripe but it shows on the inside as well.  Is there a way to assign color to only one side of the face?  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the same face, in the *Shader Editor* use the *Backface* output of an *Input > Geometry* node as factor of a *MixRGB* (or *Mix Shader*, depending on your material)